# Developer Informacion Message - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

In community  edition (published version) throws alert "Developer Information". Is it possible to remove this message?

Answer (score 0):

For community users, if you change the background image of splash page or the icon of LogoImage on splash page, you get this error.

In order not to get this error, you can use default background image(defaultsplash.png) for splash page and the default icon(logo.png) for LogoImage.

Or you can upgrade your licence.
You can check informations about licence types from the below link:
https://account.smartface.io/license